# EF6 + PostGresql - 22021: invalid byte sequence for encoding \"UTF8\": 0xc9 0x52

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postgresql

Estou tentando obter dados de um banco PostGreSql com Enconding SQL_ASCII, porém em alguns registros eu recebo a mensagem de erro *"22021: invalid byte sequence for encoding \"UTF8\": 0xc9 0x52"*

Já tentei setar o Enconding na string de conexão de diversas maneiras, mas sem sucesso, ocorre o erro *"Keyword not supported"*

Alguém sabe de alguma solução que não seja trocar o Enconding do banco para UTF8?

Comment: Qual o encoding atual do banco?

Comment: É o encode do banco é SQL_ASCII

Comment: O provider que estou utilizando é o "EntityFramework6.Npgsql -Version 3.0.7"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Más notícias. [A equipe do Npgsql desistiu do suporte ao SQL_ASCII](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/391).

Forçando diretamente o uso de `LATIN1` para `string`s, [este usuário conseguiu usar `SQL_ASCII` no sistema dele](https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql/issues/124#issuecomment-30421290). O problema é que isso dificilmente poderá ser usado juntamente com o Entity Framework, cuja atividade de parametrização é automática.

Não vejo alternativas senão a migração do banco para UTF-8, o que é bastante recomendável.

Comment: Foi adicionado suporte na versão 3.1.8, fiz testes com o EntityFramework e Dapper e funcionou, mas o que você disse de migrar para UTF-8 que é bastante recomendável é extremamente válido, inclusive isso foi dito à mim pelos próprios mantedores.

Answer (score 6):

Na versão 3.1.8 foi adicionado o suporte ao `ClientEncoding` na string de conexão, o que resolve muitos problemas: já respondi isso aqui: [Problema com acentuação no postgresql com npgsql](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/148998/problema-com-acentua%C3%A7%C3%A3o-no-postgresql-com-npgsql/149115#149115)

A solução é:

```
var sqlBuilder = new NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder
                {
                    Host = strLocal,
                    Database = strNome,
                    Username = strUser,
                    Password = strSenha,
                    Pooling = false,
                    Encoding = "windows-1252",
                    ClientEncoding = "sql-ascii"
                };

 string strConexao = sqlBuilder.ConnectionString;
```

Log da versão: https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/milestone/36?closed=1

Log da Issue: https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/392

Comment: Finalmente esse pessoal teve bom senso e implementou isso. Era só o que faltava não poder atualizar o componente por causa da codificação do banco.

Answer (score 1):

Pessoal tive o mesmo problema utilizando um banco `sql_ascii` com a versão 8.3 do Postgres.
Resolvi utilizando a versão **4.0.7** do **Npsql** e adicionando os parâmetros abaixo na string de conexão:

```
Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=lab_sis;Username=labsis_usr;Password=******;***ENCODING=LATIN1;client Encoding=LATIN1***
```