# Problema com acentuação no postgresql com npgsql

Tags: c#, postgresql, codificação-de-caracteres, npgsql

Tenho um banco de dados *postgresql* criado com *encoding SQL_ASCII* e *template0*. Quando eu tento selecionar linhas com acentos como *NÃO* dá erro, porém se os registros não tiverem acento funciona normalmente.

Erros:

> Error parsing column 6 (sempresa=0   - String)}
>
> Message = Não é possível converter bytes [C3] em índice 0 da página de código especificada para Unicode.

Estou utilizando *npgsql e Dapper*

```
<packages>
  <package id="Dapper" version="1.50.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Npgsql" version="3.1.7" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Eu tentei:

Passar *client encoding* na string de conexão. Tentei vários encodings.

```
var sqlBuilder = new NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder
{
    Host = host,
    Database = database,
    Username = user,
    Password = password,
    Pooling = false,
    ClientEncoding = "SQL_ASCII" 
    //Tentei "UNICODE", "utf8", "win-1252"
};
```

Também tentei rodar um comando antes do select para mudar o `encoding`. Tentei vários `encodings`:

```
 // Tentei: SQL_ASCII, win-1252, unicode
 connection.Execute("set client_encoding = 'SQL_ASCII'");

 var data = connection.Query<T>(strSQL);
```

Recriar o banco de dados com outro encoding não é uma opção pois a aplicação será executada em vários bancos já em produção.

Já procurei outras perguntas na rede, mas nada funcionou no meu caso.

Comment: relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/132331/2363

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após eu entrar em contato com os mantedores do NPG-SQL, na versão 3.1.8 foi adicionado suporte ao atributo `ClientEncoding`, o que resolveu o problema.

```
 var sqlBuilder = new NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder
                {
                    Host = strLocal,
                    Database = strNome,
                    Username = strUser,
                    Password = strSenha,
                    Pooling = false,
                    Encoding = "windows-1252",
                    ClientEncoding = "sql-ascii"
                };

 string strConexao = sqlBuilder.ConnectionString;
```

Porém fica a recomendação de não usar o `Encoding sql-ascii` para novos bancos de dados. O meu caso foi um caso de software legado, e não havia possibilidade de trocar o Encoding do banco.